# What are some good budget Ubuntu-compatible digital cameras?

Tags: camera

Or is there a resource on the web that lists the ones are Ubuntu compatible?

I'm thinking of ordering this one from Polaroid

http://consumerelectronicsreviews.net/polaroid-cia-1237rc-digital-camera-review-b003e47fwu/

Comment: I think, nowdays the cameras connects to the copmuters like a simple USB storage. What do you think?

Comment: What do you expect from the camera? Ability to just upload the pix to Ubuntu? Or something fancty like being able to make photos from Ubuntu controlling the camera?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most digital cameras are seen by Ubuntu as USB flash drives. While there are some that won't get along with Ubuntu, you're pretty safe in this area. Once you have your options narrowed down to 2-3 kinds you should search the forums for those models to see what others have experienced.

[Here's a pretty good page](https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/musicvideophotos/C/photos.html) on cameras/photos in Ubuntu to get you started.